# How do you re-arange the menus in the VB6 IDE?

Tags: ide, vb6

I want to move some of the menus around (especially the right-click context menu items) in the VB6 IDE.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just discovered this:

- If you click from the VB6 IDE
  View>Toolbars>Customize
- In the Toolbars tab check the Shortcut
  Menus It'll show you a floating
  "menu" called "shortcut menus". You
  can then browse through those menus
  and *move* things around.

Very  cool. I promoted some of the more
    useful features  (like "Definition")
    and (from MZ-Tools) "Procedure
    Callers" to be at the top of the
    "Code" Window menu (instead of *Cut*
    and *Paste* (which I just use the
    keyboard for anyway).

Comment: You can also use `Customize` to create your own keyboard shortcuts. http://www.angryhacker.com/blog/archive/2009/02/10/5-ways-to-be-a-more-efficient-developer-in-5.aspx

Comment: Wait, did you mean Toolbars>Customize?
I dont' see how to create shortcuts (hotkeys) from there.

Comment: @MarkJ Link is dead. Any hints on what we need to do?

Comment: @sixeyes Thanks for pointing out the dead link! It's a hacky trick: you rename the menu item using the `&` character to setup a shortcut. For instance rename `Comment Block` as `&Comment` and the shortcut will be `Alt-C`. Here's the [dead link on the wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160313051408/http://www.angryhacker.com/blog/archive/2009/02/10/5-ways-to-be-a-more-efficient-developer-in-5.aspx)